# How to attach the same row to every element of a column, creating a 2D array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a `numpy` array, say `x`, with shape:

```
(10,)
```

(i.e. a column) and one other array, say `y`, with shape:

```
(1,100)
```

(i.e. a row). I need to place a "copy" of `y` (the row) next to every element of `x` (the column), creating a new array of shape

```
(10,101)
```

What is the most efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways.  You could adjust dimensions, and concatenate.

Or you could make a target array of the right size, and copy values to it:

```
In [68]: x = np.arange(10)*10; y = np.arange(5).reshape(1,5)                                                 
In [69]: x                                                                                                   
Out[69]: array([ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
In [70]: y                                                                                                   
Out[70]: array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
In [71]: z = np.zeros((10,6),int)                                                                            
In [72]: z[:,0] = x                                                                                          
In [73]: z[:,1:].shape                                                                                       
Out[73]: (10, 5)
In [74]: z[:,1:] = y
```

Here I'm take advantage of `y` shape (1,5) which can broadcast to (10,5)

```
In [75]: z                                                                                                   
Out[75]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [10,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [20,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [30,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [40,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [50,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [60,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [70,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [80,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [90,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4]])
```

Comment: I timed our approaches. Yours is three times faster. I noted it down in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use broadcasting and concatenate:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10)
b = np.arange(100).reshape(1, 100)
c = np.concatenate([a[:, np.newaxis], np.broadcast_to(b, (len(a), b.shape[1]))], axis=1)
print(c.shape)
# (10, 101)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, making use of numpy [expand_dims](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html#numpy.expand_dims), [repeat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy.repeat) and [block](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.block.html) functions:

```python
import numpy as np

x = np.ones(10)
y = np.zeros((1, 100))

x_expanded = np.expand_dims(x, axis=1)
y_expanded = np.repeat(y, 10, axis=0)

result = np.block([x_expanded, y_expanded])
```

How it works:

- `expand_dims` adds a new dimension along *axis 1*, turning an array of shape `(10,)` into one of shape `(10, 1)`
- `repeat` copies 10 times the values of `y` along *axis 0*, generating an array of shape `(10, 100)`
- `block` yuxtaposes the two arrays, `(10, 1)` and `(10, 100)`, to conform the `result` array of shape `(10, 101)`

**Edit:** I timed my approach and @hpaulj's. **His solution is 3 times faster than mine**, so in terms of efficiency you should use his:

```python
# My approach. Benchmark: 2.690964487e-05 seg (nr of times: 10000000)
x = np.arange(10)*10
y = np.arange(100).reshape(1, 100)

x_expanded = np.expand_dims(x, axis=1)
y_expanded = np.repeat(y, 10, axis=0)

result = np.block([x_expanded, y_expanded])


# hpaulj approach. Benchmark: 7.89659798e-06 seg (nr of times: 10000000)
x = np.arange(10)*10
y = np.arange(100).reshape(1, 100)
z = np.zeros((10, 101), int)
z[:, 0] = x
z[:,1:] = y
```